# Ignoring timestamps

Tags: c++, scanf

I am trying to write some code which ignores the timestamps of the strings and reads the rest of the strings of varying lengths e.g.

```
14/07/20 18:27:02:533 ... C: SPLT 0x00 MTE_DL_RBSFN_STAT 0X00000001 0X00000000 0X00000000 0X00000000 0X00000000 0X00000000 0X00000000 0X00000000 0X00000000 0X00000000 0X00000000 0X00000000 0X00000000 0X00000000
14/07/20 18:27:02:533 ... SLOF
14/07/20 18:27:02:537 ... C: SLOF 0x00
14/07/20 18:27:02:541 forg l1 SetPortMapping 0
14/07/20 18:27:02:550 C: FORG 0x00 Ok l SetPortMapping 0
```

I am trying to use `sscanf` function to ignore the stamps and read rest of the string. This will happen in a loop. So I can not use defined `%s` and `%*s`. I need an algorithm to ignore part of the string i.e timestamps and read the remaining string. Thanks

Comment: If the length of the timestamp string is fixed, how about `std::string line, temp; std::getline(stream, temp); line = temp.substr(22);`

Comment: Otherwise, you will have to define what "timestamps" is and build an algorithm to read (and skip) them.

Comment: If the timestamp portion is of fixed length (say 22), then you can use `sscanf` and `str+22` as the 'source' string pointer. Possibly dangerous, though, and rather "Old-School C" but...

Comment: Do you know how to use `find` and `substr`?

Comment: Timestamp is not of fixed length. Also the string length is not fixed.

Comment: while(getline(File2,inFile2)). This will read my entire file which could be of 100 lines. I have to skip the time stamps and read rest of the file. Thanks

Comment: `I can not use defined %s` If the timestamps do not contain spaces you *can* use `%*s %*s %[^\n]`. Otherwise if the timestamps can contain spaces you'll need to define what exact format(s) you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You've noted that the timestamps aren't of fixed length.  However, if it's always the case that the format is `date timestamp the...rest...`, then you could get the line as a string, then use `string.find` (twice) to find the second spacebar, e.g.

```
std::string s;
while (getline(input, s)) {
   size_t loc = s.find(' ');
   loc = s.find(' ', loc + 1);
   s = s.substr(loc + 1);
}
```